# How to get Captured Part of the Regular Expression in Nim

Tags: regex, nim-lang

I want to extract "some_token" from the "some text :some_token" text.

The code below returns the full match `' :some_token'` not the captured part `'some_token'` marked with `([a-z0-9_-]+)`.

```
import re

let expr = re("\\s:([a-z0-9_-]+)$", flags = {re_study, re_ignore_case})
for match in "some text :some_token".find_bounds(expr):
  echo "'" & match & "'"
```

How it could be modified to return only the captured part?

P.S.

Also, what's the difference between `re` and `nre` modules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The submitted code does not compile (`find_bounds` returns a `tuple[first, last: int]` and not something that you can iterate with `for`). Still, it is true that find_bounds in that examples will give index bounds of the whole pattern and not the capture substring.

The following (https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2yvs) works to give the captured string:

```
import re

let expr = re("\\s:([a-z0-9_-]+)$", flags = {re_study, re_ignore_case})
var matches: array[1, string]
if "some text :some_token".find(expr, matches) >= 0:
  echo matches  # -> ["some_token"]
```

Note that in the above `matches` must have the correct length for captured groups (using a sequence will not work unless you specify the correct length). This is a known issue of `re`: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/9472

Regarding the dual existence of `re` and `nre`, summarizing from [this discussion](https://github.com/nim-lang/RFCs/issues/31):

- `nre` has a different api (more ergonomic) than `re` (closer to C API)
- `nre` had less issues than `re` in the past, but the gap has been closed in recent times (see also [open regex issues](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/labels/regex))
- it might be that in the future `nre` might be moved out from stdlib and put in a nimble package, but since this has not happened in v1, it probably will not happen before v2
- note that there is a pure nim implementation of regex ([nim-regex](https://github.com/nitely/nim-regex)) which also has an ergonomic API.